# How to update /etc/services for k8s pod / Docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I need to update my `/etc/services` file with adding some extra line to it.
But I could not find any straight answers to this.
In k8s there is an option to add **hostAliases** for `/etc/hosts` by editing deployment object but no options to update `/etc/services`

As an option, I could mount my own file but this is a too brutal way to do this IMO.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not add a cat >> in the entrypoint?

Comment: @paltaa Make sense but I need to add this config on running cluster or before container start. Also, what if I need to make changes to it?

Comment: assuming you will need to make changes to it, they will be done in the deployment.yaml or patching with a cli command, if you change the code it will trigger the pipelines and trigger the container update, which is still modifying something

Comment: @paltaa Could you provide example of how to supply cat command for the deployment.yaml? Also, in case of docker-compose, I think I could use the command section?

Comment: @paltaa You can add your answer here, so I can mark it as a resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing your `/etc/services` with a mounted `ConfigMap` would have the merit of being **able to make updates while your Pods are running**.

If you don't want to use that technique, you can use a [PostStart Lifecycle Hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/) to add lines whenever your Pods start or restart:

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo '[new-line]' >> /etc/services"]
```